# extracting subnet using Rinanalyzer

Tags: json, cytoscape

I loaded a network (.json) file which was generated from the Ring server. After loading, I am trying to extract a subnet from the entire network but the options in the Rinanalyzer plugin is disabled! Can anyone suggest me how to do it? or other ways to extract the subnet?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HfcR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run the Analyze Network first and create the view, but I haven't looked at RINAlyzer in a long time.  Let us know if that doesn't work and we can dive into it more completely...

Comment: I did run the analyze network option to create the view but still the options to extract subnetwork is disabled!